# Trend in equivalence classes of $ (x,y) \in R \iff x-y \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Question:

Define the following equivalence relation on the real numbers:

$ (x,y) \in R \iff x-y \in \mathbb{Z}$

Compute $ \ [-2], [-1], [0], [1], [2] $. Do you see a trend?

My attempt:

$ [-2] = \{ { y \in \mathbb{R} : -2-y \in \mathbb{Z} }\}$

$ [-1] = \{ { y \in \mathbb{R} : -1-y \in \mathbb{Z} }\}$

$ [0] = \{ { y \in \mathbb{R} : 0-y \in \mathbb{Z} }\}$

$ [1] = \{ { y \in \mathbb{R} : 1-y \in \mathbb{Z} }\}$

$ [2] = \{ { y \in \mathbb{R} : 2-y \in \mathbb{Z} }\}$

Will all of the above equivalence classes be equal to $ \mathbb{Z}$? Is that the trend?

Comment: Looks like it. I'm not quite sure what else the question would be looking for.

Comment: What else can it be?

Comment: I can't think of anything else

Comment: $[-2]=[-1]=[1]=[2]=[0]=Z $.

Comment: That seems correct.  If $x \in \mathbb Z$ then $x\pm k \in \mathbb Z$ and if $x\not \in \mathbb Z$ then $x\pm k \not \in \mathbb Z$ and therefore $\{y| y\pm k \in \mathbb Z\} = \{y|y\in \mathbb Z\} = \mathbb Z$.  So $[k] = \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

It is clear that if $a,b\in \Bbb Z $ then
$a-b\in \Bbb Z $ and $[a]=[b] $.

on the other hand
$$[0]=\{x\in \Bbb R \;\;:\;\;x\in \Bbb Z\}=\Bbb Z $$

thus

if $a \in \Bbb Z $ then $[a]=[0]=\Bbb Z $
$$=[1]=[-1]=[2]=[-2] $$

Comment: The equivalent classes are called the reals modulus 1.

Answer (score 1):

They are all $\mathbb{Z}$. In fact, if $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, then
$$
\{x\in\mathbb{R} \mid x+n\in\mathbb{Z}\} = \mathbb{Z}.
$$
*Proof:*
Denote $A:=\{x\in\mathbb{R} \mid x+n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Then
$$
x\in A \iff x+n \in \mathbb{Z} \iff x+n-n\in \mathbb{Z} \iff x\in \mathbb{Z}.
$$